# Physical sequence of a multi-column clustered index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am wondering how the database will store a multi-column clustered indexed table.

E.g.

I have a table like this:

```
product area price date
Wood NewYork 20 20111102
Iron NewYork 155 20111102
Stone NewYork 33 20111102
Wood Boston 21 20111102
Iron Boston 150 20111102
Stone Boston 30 20111102

Wood NewYork 19 20111101
Iron NewYork 165 20111101
Stone NewYork 32 20111101
Wood Boston 22 20111101
Iron Boston 159 20111101
Stone Boston 34 20111101
```

The majority of my queries are to get average price for a certain product on a particular day.  Primary key is set to be `(product, area, date)`, there is a clustered index on this primary key.

Question 1.
How will the database physically store this data? If in the sequence of `(product, area, date)`, it might look like

```
product area price date
Wood NewYork .. 20111102
Wood Boston .. 20111102
Wood ... .. 20111101
Wood ...  .. 20111101

Iron NewYork  50 20111102
Iron Boston 30 20111102

Stone NewYork 19 20111101
Stone Boston 165 20111101
```

But wouldn't it be faster if the physical records are ordered by dates, then the DB can load  the rows with less disk operation? If this is the case, do I have control over the ordering?

Question 2.
The clustered index doesn't seem to offer performance benefit to the query. After I added a non-clustered index on date, the speed is 1 sec for most queries (50 secs when there is no index on date). Why is there such a huge difference?

Answer (score 3):

The **clustering index** defines the physical order, so in your case, you'd have

```
product  area      price  date

Iron     Boston     30    20111102
Iron     NewYork    50    20111102

Stone    Boston    165    20111101
Stone    NewYork    19    20111101

Wood     Boston     ..    20111102
Wood     NewYork    ..    20111102
```

and so on. This is a great index **if** you always select by those three columns - if you always select `product`, `area`, and `date`. This index however does **not** help you anything if you select only by `date` - a composite index will only be used if you use / specify the n left-most columns; this index here could be used for `product`, `product` and `area`, or all three columns - but not for any other column(s).

Depending on your needs, you could also

- put a **non-clustered** primary key on (`product, area, date`) (if that's really the only combination of columns to make your rows unique) - or think about a surrogate `INT IDENTITY` column to simplify this
- put a **clustered** index on e.g. (`date, product`) so that you have your data ordered more in the way that you need it for querying